# Sitecore 8: SheerResponse dialog popup no longer working?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8

I've had a Task communicate problems to the user running it via SheerResponse.Alert(), but it doesn't seem to be working anymore in Sitecore 8.x.

Is this a known issue? Is there a SPEAK alternative I should be using instead?

```
Stacktrace System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.SheerResponse.Alert(String text, String[] arguments) at...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore Sheer UI is no longer supported with Sitecore 8, you need SPEAK to make it work.
Please use this reference it has code piece which shows how can you new method Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Dialogs.showModalDialog for showing popup window with Sitecore 8. 
[Reference](http://jockstothecore.com/sitecore-8-ribbon-button-transfiguration/)